# Using type hint Any in Django - NameError: name 'Any' is not defined

Tags: python, django

When I use the autocomplete suggestion in VSCode to make a `get_context_data()` function:

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

I get a `NameError`:
`NameError: name 'Any' is not defined`

I am new to using type hints in Python - do I need to import something for type `Any`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Any` in this context is a type annotation. You need to import it from the typing module for it to be recognized.

```
from typing import Any
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: Also needed to import `Dict`

Comment: Note that with Python 3.10+ the typing versions of List, Dict, Set and Frozenset are being deprecated. For more information on typing in general you should read over the official documentation. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing%20dict#typing.Dict)

Comment: @pgrad starting from python 3.9, [actually](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)